# How do I make an http request that will work on 32-bit, 64-bit windows as well as on Mac (VBA Excel)?

Tags: vba, excel

First week programming with VBA. I am creating an excel plugin and will be making a few HTTP requests to get json data. I need to make it cross-platform, but I am really confused on the different varieties that VBA has to make/receive http requests. Their docs aren't clear on what platforms it will work on. I only have 64-bit Office & windows to test on but this needs to work on 32-bit as well as on Mac. I am using the following and it works for me but even after googling I have no idea if it will work elsewhere:

```
Dim myURL As String: myURL = "https://blah.com"
Dim req As MSXML2.XMLHTTP60: Set req = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60

req.Open "GET", myURL, False
req.Send
DEBUG.Print req.responseText
```

Does MSXML2.XMLHTTP60 work on all platforms or is there something else I should be using?

Comment: Works for me (Win7 64bit, 32-bit Office 2010)

Comment: Your biggest problem is going to be getting it to work on the Mac. Pretty sure you're not going to have access to any of the ActiveX objects that can download files over http on Mac.

Comment: @tmdean: is there a workaround for Mac?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It *does* work _on Windows 32- or 64-bit, as we have working code that calls the MSXML parser in both 32-bit and 64-bit DLLs.  It has been installed along with the operating system, since at least Windows 2000.

Interestingly enough, I too can't find documentation from Microsoft that explicitly states that MSXML is available on either 32- or 64-bit.  Perhaps it is implied by the fact that it is deployed with the OS.

Here's evidence, beyond my ancedote, where someone was comparing the performance between 32 and 64-bit versions:  http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/52330c5c-2eae-493c-9560-caf3dd21c14f/why-64bit-msxml2domdocument60-is-much-slower-then-32bit?forum=xmlandnetfx

The Mac part is harder.  I think that the answer for MSXML is "no".

1. You might consider [conditional compilation](http://www.utteraccess.com/wiki/index.php/Conditional_Compilation#Built_In_Compiler_Constants), to use a different XML parser on Mac.
2. Others seemed to have some luck with the [QueryTables](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2106568?threadID=2106568) object in Excel, and bypass a parser entirely.  This may or may not be appropriate to your scenario.

Comment: I think "no", but maybe you could find a separate parser for the Mac and then use conditional compilation... Let me update my answer.

Comment: Or the QueryTable built-in Excel object might be do it, depending on your situation.

Comment: As for point #1: I don't really even need an XML parser, per say. I just need to make an HTTP request that would work on all platforms

Answer (score 2):

I used the same component in XP for years.  It should work on most platforms unless you're wanting to support legacy systems.

From [Microsoft's Xml Team](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/xmlteam/archive/2006/10/23/using-the-right-version-of-msxml-in-internet-explorer.aspx)
Dated 23 Oct 2006 6:01 PM

- Use MSXML 6.0 - it is “in the box” on Vista and available for
  download on Win2k, XP, and 2003.  It has the best security,
  performance, reliability, and W3C conformance MSXML 3.0 is our
  preferred “fallback” - It is installed on every OS from a fully
  patched Win2k SP4 installation on up, so it requires
  “zero-deployment” and is serviced regularly with the OS
- MSXML 4.0 was released to the web about 5 years ago, but at this
  point has been superseded by MSXML 6.0 and is only intended to
  support legacy applications
- MSXML 5.0 for Microsoft Office Applications is purpose-built for
  Office applications and isn’t intended for broad deployment. 
  Internet Explorer 7 actually has the MSXML5 components
  "off-by-default" in the Internet zone so your customers will get a
  goldbar for each MSXML5 control on a page if your code tries to
  instantiate it.  The best recommendation is to avoid MSXML5 in your
  web apps (only machines with Office 2003 or higher will have it,
  anyway.).